# How can i make 1 viewcontroller slide up from bottom

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, slide

I have 2 viewcontrollers.The first one should occupy major portion of the screen and second one should be at the bottom portion

How do i make the bottom viewcontroller slide up to occupy the entire screen

Comment: your question is good , in this place use modal class it is easy to work\

Answer (score 1):

you can use `addchildViewController` method of UIViewController

basically when you want to show the other VC. do this in first

```
let vc = SecondVC()
self.addChildViewController(vc)
self.view.addSubView(vc.view)

//now set constraints or set the vc.view frame to whatever position you want
```